# Appium sees iOS app elements as a flat list with no nesting

Tags: ios, swift, nested, appium, hierarchy

We are currently in development of both iOS (swift) and Android (kotlin) native apps, and I'm seeing something strange with the iOS app.

In the code we have multiple components with nested elements within them, but when inspecting the app with appium, I only get a flat list of elements with no hierarchy between them.

screenshot of the inspector:

[image]

Of course in Android we do see the appropriate nesting of the elements in appium.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: check accessible property value of your views.
official appium docs state somewhere in their documentation about this specific property and its value.

Comment: Accessibility id is working correctly, and I am able to find elements using it. 
It is just that the hierarchy is not represented here so I cannot look for child elements under a specific element.